# Run Chrome kiosk mode in windows 10 assigned access

Tags: windows, google-chrome, powershell, kiosk-mode

It is a good news that Windows 10 assigned access support running Desktop Application(Win 8.1 only support running universal apps).  I want to run Chrome's kiosk mode using --kiosk in command line.

The bottom of this article have a tutorial.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt219051(v=vs.85).aspx

However, I am very new to Powershell.  Can anyone explain

1. how to launch Chrome's kiosk mode by powershell?  My command line is
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk  http://my.website.com
2. how to use the script at the bottom of the article?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I had to change this line:

```
"`nEnabled is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.IsEnabled()
```

To this:

```
"`nEnabled is set to " + $DefaultShellObject.Shell
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is months after you asked but I just did this and it is working. Your line should look like this:

```
$ShellLauncherClass.SetCustomShell($KioskUser_SID, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --kiosk http://my.website.com", ($null), ($null), $restart_shell)
```